# Need to count column cell value of having same type

Tags: asp.net

I have a repeater control in which i display record as below..

```
Name Type noOfItems Amount

Abc   A      2        100
cbc   B      1        200
xyz   A      1        100
ret   c      3         50
wes   B      1        200
```

In this I show 3 rows.. what I want is to count No. of Type with their total `noofItems`

Something like...

```
 Total no of items:  (3) A, (2) B, (1) C
 Total Amount:       (2) 100, (2) 200, (1) 50
```

Kindly try to help me out..please..

Thank you,..

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Bind the ItemDataBound event of the repeater and keep dictionaries with the values in there. When the footer is being attached, set the values wherever you need it.

In the page:

```
<asp:Repeater ... OnItemDataBound="rptRepeaterName_ItemDataBound" ...>
```

In the code behind:

```
protected void rptRepeaterName_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
         // logic to count occurences of A, B, C and amounts in each their own dictionary ex: typeDictionary[type] += 1; amountDictionary[amount] += 1;
    }
    else if (e.Item.ItemType = ItemType.Footer)
    {
        // display values stored in both dictionaries
    }
}
```

Comment: but the thing is that in my table Types are not fix.There are so many types in that..so wat can i do for that...I need to count all Individual Types Total Amount like A(100+100),B(200+200) and so on....

Will try to do that..?

Comment: The way a dictionary works is that it stores a value for myDictionary[type1], a value for myDictionary[type2], so if `type` in my example is a variable, the count for each type will be calculated and available in the second portion of the code I've written. You can loop through a dictionary's key-value pairs to extract the counts for each type and amount.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more idea, you call the amount using a function that also keep the totals, and you use them at the end of your repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myId" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%#GetTheAmount(Container.DataItem)%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

Total Amount: <%=cTotalAmount%>
Total Lines: <%=cTotalLines%>
```

and on code behind

```
public int cTotalAmount = 0;
public int cTotalLines = 0;

public string GetTheAmount(object oItem)
{
    int cCurrentAmount = (int)DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "Amount");
    cTotalLines++;
    cTotalAmount += cCurrentAmount;

    return cCurrentAmount.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aristos,

I think its good. What i need it to find total with individual type like A(Total Amount),B(Total Amount) ...

Comment: @Hitesh in the code, you also get the data of the A, or B, and make the different totals... eg: switch(DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "Type")){case 'A': TotalA++;break; case 'B': TotalB++; break; etc...}

Comment: This is true in case of fix Type,

But what when there is multiple Types is there in table data....?

Comment: @hitesh make a list with a custom class that include the total and the types... if I have time I will make the code later.

Comment: @Arstos thanks.

Will Try it...if you have time will try to make that too.